# KendoUI MVC grid pop-up , how to return the value of selected combobox item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i am new to Kendo UI as well as  javascript.Using MVC Kendo grid editing with Pop-up mode.I created custom template page(under EditorTemplates folder) for editing when pop-up window opens.There are some textboxes and Kendo Combobox widgets in that page to update records.
Values that coming from textboxes can be send to controller but selected item's value on combobox couldn't be send to controller.How can i do that?

**View(Razor)**

```
 @model PROJECT.UI.WebService.Proxy.DSrvINFO.PERSONALINFORMATIONS
<div class="row">
<div class="span10">
 <div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;height: 500px;" >
<table width="100%" cellspacing="5" style="margin: 20px">
 <tr>
<td width="10%">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NAME)
  </td>
 <td width="40%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NAME)
</td>
<td width="10%">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SURNAME)
</td>
<td width="40%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SURNAME) </td>
   <td width="10%">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDTYPE)
                </td>
                <td width="40%">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
        .Name("IDTYPES") 
        .DataTextField("DESCRIPTION").HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:220px"}) /
        .DataValueField("REFERENCEID") 
                // .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                     .Placeholder("SELECT")

                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
       read.Action("Details", "Items", new { Code =      "IDTYPE", addEmptyRow = false });

                        }).ServerFiltering(true);
                    }))
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
           </div>
           </div>
```

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult PersonUpdate([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,Guid id,string name,string surname,string[] IDTYPES) {     ....
```

Here is sample header data that captured from chrome when press update button on  on Pop-Up window.IDTYPES values are coming from combobox's selected item object.I need to pass some values of IDTYPE(eg.IDTYPES.CODE,IDTYPES.ID,IDTYPES.REFERENCEID ) to controller from view.

```
sort:
group:
filter:
CITIZENNO:-
ID:78ef069f-c31b-4828-81e8-4ede52ee0818
NAME:ABDULAZIZ
SURNAME:AL GARNI
IDTYPES.ID:69bd3ef7-fc80-4f26-a978-963ed670d3fe
IDTYPES.REFERENCEID:57ff1ea9-6cb4-4d7e-abc7-caa367fd4627
IDTYPES.CODE:3
IDTYPES.DESCRIPTION:PASSPORT ID
IDTYPES.PARENTID:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
IDTYPES.ISSELECTED:false
IDTYPES.COUNT:0
IDTYPES.ISACTIVE:false
IDTYPES.ISDEFAULT:false
IDTYPES[ID]:69bd3ef7-fc80-4f26-a978-963ed670d3fe
IDTYPES[REFERENCEID]:57ff1ea9-6cb4-4d7e-abc7-caa367fd4627
IDTYPES[CODE]:3
IDTYPES[DESCRIPTION]:PASSPORT ID
IDTYPES[PARENTID]:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
IDTYPES[ISSELECTED]:false
IDTYPES[COUNT]:0
IDTYPES[ISACTIVE]:false
IDTYPES[ISDEFAULT]:false
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly. Are you trying to get the selected value from the `ComboBox` and pass it to the controller? Are you saying that the `ComboBox` attaches more than just the `DESCRIPTION` and the `REFERENCEID` to the control?

Comment: I am trying to do exactly that you said.I cannot figure out how to pass combobox's selected value(which is IDTYPES.DESCRIPTION on code ) to controller.

Answer (score 0):

The value from the `ComboBox` can be retrieved as described in the [documentation](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/api.html), using JQuery. After that, you can just post it to your controller using Ajax:

```
var selectedValue = $("#IDTYPES").data("kendoComboBox").text();
$.ajax({
   url: "@Url.Action(actionName, controllerName)" + "/?id="+userid+"&name="+username+"&surname="+usersurname+"&idtype="+selectedValue,
   success: function(){ /*handle success*/},
   error: function(){ /*handle error*/}
});
```

You would also need to change your Controller Action definition as bellow. As far as I understand you don't need all the values of the `ComboBox`, but only the selected value:

```
public ActionResult PersonUpdate([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,Guid id,string name,string surname,string IDTYPE)
```

Comment: Can i send only IDTYPE's selected value data with jquery?
Other data s on textboxes can be send without any problem to controller.

Comment: Of course. Once you have the data, you can do whatever you want with it. I do have a question though: don't you send all the values to the same controller/action?

Comment: Yes,this is the custom template page of Kendo grid pop-up  for editing.On this page there are 16 data fields to edit.4 of them are created with Kendo combobox widget.Other fields are getting input from textbox and pass  input values to SAME action method on controller.I can pass values on textboxes but cannot pass selected item's value on combobox to controller.

Comment: Now i can see the selected item's value on js alert pop-up screen :)
Last step is ,passing this value to controller method:

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".k-grid-update").click(function () {
            var selectedValue = $("#IDTYPES").data("kendoComboBox").text();
            alert(selectedValue);
//   TO DO: to pass selected value to Action method as parameter
        });

Comment: You select the `ComboBox` by using `$("#IDTYPES").data("kendoComboBox")` and then you attach `.text()` to get the displayed value (`DESCRIPTION` in your case) or `.value()` to get the id (`REFERENCEID` in your case).

Comment: I tried this:

  $(".k-grid-update").click(function () {
            var selectedText = $("#IDTYPES").data("kendoComboBox").text();
            alert(selectedText);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("PersonUpdate", "Administrator")' + "&IDTYPES=" + selectedText,
                success: function () { alert("Success") },
                error: function () { alert("error") }
            });

getting error message: http://localhost:63186/Administrator/PersonUpdate&IDTYPES=NATIONAL%20ID 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Just to notice, i have no such page like this "PersonUpdate",it is just a Action method in Administrator controller to get updated data's and send them to Model layer to update DB records.

Comment: The `PersonUpdate` action is the one you posted in the question. You can modify the name according to your actions.

Comment: @Rudresh 
I tried your suggestion and got error:    'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ReadOnlyDataSourceBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Update' and no extension method 'Update' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ReadOnlyDataSourceBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @balron, the solution Rudresh suggested was not valid. You are getting this error because the `Kendo Data Source` object does not have such a method.

Comment: i m stucked at here:
 var selectedValue = $("#IDTYPES").data("kendoComboBox").text();

tried:
url: '@Url.Action("PersonUpdate ", "Administrator")' ..... 
It searches for that PersonUpdate page and returns error.

Comment: Do you have an action named `PersonUpdate` in your `Administrator` controller?

Comment: Yes,i wrote it on my first message.

Comment: @balron, I just looked at your URL. You are missing a `/` and have an `&` in the wrong place. Since you only want to send the `IDTYPES` value, change the Ajax url object to `url: "@Url.Action(actionName, controllerName)" + "/?idtype="+selectedText`

Comment: Thanks,but your Ajax code gives error so i changed it to 
url: '@Url.Action("PersonUpdate", "Administrator")' + "&IDTYPES=" + selectedValue, .... 

Now when i watch requests chrome's network tab.2 request has been send to controller.First one is my custom request that created by ajax(@Url.Action method) gives error: "Request Method:GET",
"Status Code:400 Bad Request","Request URL:http://localhost:63186/Administrator/PersonUpdate&IDTYPES=PASSPORT%20ID".This request also has any data.

Comment: 2nd request is created by Kendo combobox to update data.It passes data's (except combobox's value) to controller without any problem.
Contains form-data : 
CITIZENNO:-
ID:78ef069f-c31b-4828-81e8-4ede52ee0818
NAME:ABDULAZIZ
SURNAME:AL GARNI
IDTYPES.ID:331bb79f-614d-4014-8962-21a152790880

Comment: I realize that the data that i want to pass to controller needs to be hooked into grid/Combobox's default UPDATE request .So 1 request would be send to controller with all data's.